# How to prevent people from adding other people in an iMessage group?

Tags: messages

Is there some setting / block / third party app where I can prevent someone adding another person to group messages?

Answer (score 2):

In short, no, it cannot be done.

No-one "owns" an iMessage group, it's entirely ad-hoc - so who would be the moderator of who can & cannot be in it?

What you can do is leave the room when you are invited or turn on do not disturb for a noisy room if you keep being added by “helpful” “friends”.

Comment: Do you know of any apps or softwares that can automatically remove people?